# WebClient response to list of object

Tags: c#, json, oop, webrequest

How can I cast my WebClient JSON response to list of objects that represents the json response?
For example, I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "posts" [
        { 
           "content": "Hello world",
           "user" : {
                "id": 5,
                "username": "foo"
           }
        }, 
        { 
           "content": "Foobar",
           "user" : {
                "id": 3,
                "username": "baz"
           }
        }, 
    ]
}
```

And I have 2 classs:

```
class Post
{
     public string Content;
     public User User;
}
class User
{
     public int Id;
     public string Username;
}
```

Now I want to send a request with WebRequest and cast my JSON response to list of those Posts. How can I do that?

Comment: As in *Deserialize* ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/json-deserialize-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to let a [JSON library](http://james.newtonking.com/json) deserialize the response to the target object:

```
var posts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Post>>(responseText);
```